How to implement telegram pull up to see next channel in React Native Reanimated with FlatList
I'm a React Native developer. I want to implement a "pull up to see next channel" feature in React Native with react native reanimated with FlatList/FlashList. I need a button at the bottom of my list, e.g., "Click or swipe to see more," and when the user clicks that button, it should fetch some data. However, when the user scrolls further down, the button must hide, and an animated box, similar to Telegram's "next channel" box, should be shown.
Telegram next channel feature
react native v0.72.0;
react native reanimated v3.9.0
react-native-gesture-handler: v2.16.2
I tried to implement it, but I encountered a significant issue. When the user scrolls down quickly from the top, I can't detect the background scrolling and don't run the animation, only showing the button. I want the animation to run when the user reaches the end.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
